# Ruby Static method with local scope

Tags: ruby, methods, static, module, include

The title sounds rediculous because it is. My biggest issue is actually trying to figure out what question to ask.

1. The goal: To be able to implement the code as described below OR to figure out what terminology I should be using to search for the correct answer.
2. The issue: I wish to have a system where classes register "processors" via a method within the class definition. eg:

   ```
   class RunTheseMethodsWhenICallProcess
     Include ProcessRunner

     add_processor :a_method_to_run
     add_processor :another_method_to_run

     def a_method_to_run
       puts "This method ran"
     end

     def another_method_to_run
       puts "another method ran"
     end

   end

   Module ProcessRunner
     def process
        processors.each {|meth| self.send(meth)}
     end
   end
   ```

My issues are mostly with understanding the scope and reference of the class to make them interact. As it stands, I have been able to add a static method 'add_processor' by calling class.extend(AClass) in the included method and adding in the class there.

The idea for this syntax was inspired by DataMappers 'property' and 'before' methods. Even with the code checked out, I am having a touch of trouble following it.

Thanks so much for any help you can offer.

Comment: HA. I had just opened it to do the same thing when I realized. I add a gist too, if someone wants to use git instead

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1172736

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, the following will do what you want.

It initializes each class (or module) including `ProcessRunner` to have an empty array in `@@processors`. Additionally it adds class methods `processors` (a simple getter) and `add_processor`.
The `process` method had to be adjusted to use the class method. In fact, you could add a wrapper for this, but I think that would be to verbose for such a sample.

```
module ProcessRunner

  module ClassMethods
    def add_processor(processor)
      processors << processor
    end

    def processors
      class_variable_get :@@processors
    end
  end

  def self.included(mod)
    mod.send :class_variable_set, :@@processors, []

    mod.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def process
    self.class.processors.each {|meth| self.send(meth)}
  end

end

class RunTheseMethodsWhenICallProcess
  include ProcessRunner

  add_processor :a_method_to_run
  add_processor :another_method_to_run

  def a_method_to_run
    puts "This method ran"
  end

  def another_method_to_run
    puts "another method ran"
  end

end
```